# Get header section text in QHeaderView

Tags: python, pyqt, qheaderview

I am subclassing a QHeaderView within a QTableWidget to provide custom functionality for hiding/showing sections. Is there a way to get the text of a section from within the header view? I know I can do this from within the scope of the table, but that is not what I am trying to do.

I realize the data is stored internally in a model, however the following test just returns "None":

```
self.model().index(0,0).data()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the model assigned to the [`QHeaderView`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html) and get the text using the [`headerData()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#headerData) method:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class HeaderView(QtWidgets.QHeaderView):
    def text(self, section):
        if isinstance(self.model(), QtCore.QAbstractItemModel):
            return self.model().headerData(section, self.orientation())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(10, 4)
    w.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(
        ["section-{}".format(i) for i in range(w.columnCount())]
    )

    horizontal_headerview = HeaderView(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, w)
    w.setHorizontalHeader(horizontal_headerview)

    print(horizontal_headerview.text(1))

    vertical_headerview = HeaderView(QtCore.Qt.Vertical, w)
    w.setVerticalHeader(vertical_headerview)

    print(vertical_headerview.text(2))

    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Wow so you need to call the header of the model of the header! I was trying to get to the data directly, which of course did not work.